# "No identity" error in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've worked on 1.06 version of Hyperledger Fabric.

For "Fabcar" tutorial, when I generate a lot of transactions at the same time through "Invoke.js"(I used loop), an error message is shown during execution and stops transactions from being sent, which is:

"No identity has been assigned to this client"

I'm not able to send transactions due to this error. I'm so sure that client is valid because I have only one client.

Is this a bug?

Could you please tell me how to resolve this error if you know?

I would really appreciate if you help me solve it.

Answer (score -1):

the below link might be useful for you.
[How to assign identity to fabric-client instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536308/how-to-assign-identity-to-fabric-client-instance)

And I faced the same issue as well, however it is resolved after adding the below line, i.e., channel initialization.

```
`await channel.initialize({
 discover: true
 });`
```

source: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/tutorial-discovery.html