# How to assign identity to fabric-client instance?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am unable to install node chaincode using fabric-node-sdk.
I am getting the following error:

> installChaincode error No identity has been assigned to this client

I am using following script

```
const Client = require("fabric-client");
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");
const client = new Client();
const deploy = async () => {
  const connectionOpts = {
    name: "peer1",
    "request-timeout": 7000,
    pem: path.resolve(
      os.homedir,
      "/fabric-samples/chaincode-docker-devmode/msp/signcerts/peer.pem"
    ),
    "ssl-target-name-override": "peer"
  };
  const peer = client.newPeer("grpc://172.18.0.3:7052", connectionOpts);
  const request = {
    targets: peer,
    chaincodePath: path.resolve(
      os.homedir + "/fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/node"
    ),
    chaincodeId: "myc",
    chaincodeVersion: "v0",
    chaincodeType: "node"
  };

  const result = await client.installChaincode(request, 6000);
  console.log(await result);
};

deploy();
```

How do I assign identity to client?
In the documentation, it is not demonstrated what arguments it required and how to assign identity.

Answer (score 0):

Peer node want to know who is making the transaction. Try using this method before the install chincode transaction:

```
client.setAdminSigningIdentity(private_key, certificate, mspid)
```

Where:
**private_key**:    the private key PEM string
**certificate**:    the PEM-encoded string of certificate
**mspid**:  The Member Service Provider id for the local signing identity (i.e 'Org1MSP')

In the chaincode install request, you need the txId:

```
client.setAdminSigningIdentity(private_key, certificate, mspid)
const request = {
  targets: peer,
  chaincodePath: path.resolve(
    os.homedir + "/fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/node"
  ),
  chaincodeId: "myc",
  chaincodeVersion: "v0",
  chaincodeType: "node",
  txId: client.newTransactionID(true)
};

const result = await client.installChaincode(request, 6000);
console.log(await result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still giving some error UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Endorser
Do you know any article or tutorial in which it is demonstrated from scratch?

Comment: I have a little example on my github page, but try this last change:   `const peer = client.newPeer("grpc://172.18.0.3:7051", connectionOpts);`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as well and it is resolved after adding the below line, i.e., channel initialization.

await channel.initialize({ discover: true });

source: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/tutorial-discovery.html